# How to give default argument if starred expression is empty

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function call to a `tkinter OptionMenu`, that looks like this:

```
tk.OptionMenu(container, targetVar, *list(accountMap))
```

`accountMap` is a dictionary of values I'd like to appear in the `Optionmenu`, however in some scenarios it may be that the dictionary is empty, meaning the starred expression doesn't return any arguments, and the function call to `OptionMenu` complains not enough arguments have been given. How can I add a default value of an empty string only if the starred expression returns nothing?

Comment: Note that you're only passing the keys, if any, of `accountMap` with `*list(accountMap)`. I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: To expand on what Moses said, if `accountMap = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}`, then what you're doing is equivalent to `tk.OptionMenu(container, targetVar, 'a', 'b')`. If you want `tk.OptionMenu(container, targetVar, a=1, b=2)`, use `**`.

Comment: @AlexHall That's close to what they're doing, however, we don't know which of the positional arguments will come first, which makes it worse.

Comment: The arguments after `targetVar` are the titles of the items in the option menu. That's why you need at least one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*(accountMap or [""])
```

The `list` is actually redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a one line if statement:

```
tk.OptionMenu(container, targetVar, *accountMap if accountMap else [' '])
```

this works as an empty dictionary returns `false`.

The documentation says [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) what values are considered `false` if you are interested.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use a more complicated expression:

```
tk.OptionMenu(container, targetVar, *list(accountMap if accountMap else default))
```